# React admin AutocompleteInput does not take value on first click

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have added AutocompleteInput for selecting my authors. When I search the name of the author in AutocompleteInput and click on the same I want to display, it doesn’t show me the selected value. And when I do this the second time, it shows the previously selected value.

Here's my code,

```
     <AutocompleteInput source="AuthorUid" label="Author" choices={this.state.authorList}))}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved this issue by creating a custom Autocomplete input for it. I couldn't figure out what was the problem with React admin's AutocompleteInput.

My custom component ->

```
 renderSelectField = ({ input, label, meta: { touched, error }, children, ...custom }) => {
    const dropdownMenuProps = {
        menuStyle: {
            top: "360px",
            height: "347px",
            left: "79px",
        },
    }

    return(
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <SelectField
                floatingLabelText={label}
                errorText={touched && error}
                {...input}
                dropDownMenuProps={dropdownMenuProps}
                onChange={(event, index, value) => input.onChange(value)}
                children={children}
                {...custom}/>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

I used my custom component like ->

```
<Field name="AuthorUid" component={this.renderSelectField} label="Author">
             { authors.map((author) => 
                <MenuItem value={author.id} primaryText={author.name} />
             })}
</Field>
```